# How do I configure IE10 Group Policy Settings on Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, proxy, group-policy, internet-explorer

Where do I find the proxy server setting while creating a group policy?

I know that IE 10 removed the IE Maintenance Policy.  I read that you need to go through the Preference route.  However, even there, the "new" option only lets you add an IE5-8, there's nothing about IE 10.

Can someone tell me where Microsoft has moved the option to set the domain-wide policy setting?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to import Administrative Templates into your GPO folder on sysvol? I don't think 2008 would even be aware of IE10.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess here that the answer is down to not having the relevant administrative templates, since I don't have the resources available to verify.

Server 2008 R2 provided ADM/ADMX files wouldn't be aware of IE10, so you'll need to import the ADMX templates.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=37009 says that if you install IE10 on the server, the templates are installed automatically. However, you will probably still need to import them into your sysvol folder to roll them out in your domain.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the templates from here, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=37009 , but it doesn't seem to do the trick. I need to manually import them? I'll give that a shot. I only wish I knew where they were installed

Comment: Does anyone have a tutorial on how to do this?  I've looked, but nothing i've tried seems to work.  I followed directions of putting the ADMX files in the PolicyDefinitions folder and the ADML in PolicyDefinitions\us-en.  Unfortunately, i don't see anything new.  and when it comes to importing new administrative templates into the GPO, only ADM files are allowed.  I can't do anything with ADML or ADMX files.

Answer (score 0):

There's no setting within administrative templates available for the proxy configuration. A proxy for IE10 may be set through user configuration\preferences\control panel\internet settings.

Answer (score 0):

It still won't work unless you have RSAT on windows 8 or if you use Windows Server 2012.
Internel Explorer 10 GPO settings have been depreciated on Windows Server 2008 R2.
There are workarounds, try Edugeek.